# Change UTF-8 charset to ISO/IEC 8859-2:1999 in href

Tags: php, html

I have a very simple form, consisting of two files:

FORM.PHP

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">

<input type='text' name = 'name'  value="ł ą ź ć ę ó"  >    

<input id='submit' type='submit' name = 'submit' value="SEND">

</form>`
```

and TEST.PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

echo "<a href='http://myaddress/$name/'>NAME</a>"
?>
```

In the form field 'name' fill Polish characters (ł ą ź ć ę ó)

When you click SEND script generates me a link of the form:

```
"<a href='http://myaddress/l a ź ć e ó/'>NAME</a>"
```

A link should generate in the form of:

```
"<a href='http://myaddress/%B3+%B1+%BC+%E6+%EA+%F3/'>NAME</a>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%xx` encoded form is [*percent-encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or "URL encoding". You can produce it using the [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) function. That function takes the raw bytes of your string and turns them into percent encoded groups. The exact output therefore depends on what bytes exactly you feed in, meaning what encoding your text is in.

If you need "ź" to encode to `%BC`, then it must be encoded in ISO-8859-2 (as you say). There are two ways to get that:

1. Ensure your form is submitted as ISO-8859-2 by adding an appropriate attribute:

   ```
   <form accept-charset="iso-8859-2">
   ```
2. If you don't submit in the encoding you need, then instead convert it on the server:

   ```
   $name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2', $_POST['name']);
   ```

Then `rawurlencode($name)` should result in `%B3+%B1+%BC+%E6+%EA+%F3`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

echo "<a href='http://myaddress/' . urlencode($name) . '/'>NAME</a>"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **urlencode(str)**. And **urldecode(str)** to reverse.

```
$name = urlencode($_POST['name']);

echo "<a href='http://myaddress/$name/'>NAME</a>"
```

This will result into something like,

```
<a href='http://myaddress/%C5%82+%C4%85+%C5%BA+%C4%87+%C4%99+%C3%B3/'>NAME</a>
```

Refer to 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php